# Proving $(n!)^3<n^n\times\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)^{2n}$ with high school math

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Show the following with high school math:
>   $$(n!)^3<n^n\times\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)^{2n}$$

It's given after an article on the [Arithmetic Mean-Geometric Mean inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means), so I suppose it's solved using that.

Comment: `so I suppose it's solved using that` .  So, what's your progress so far?

Comment: Do you know "mathematical induction" ?

Comment: I formatted your math expressions using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/409). Please double-check that the revision matches your intention.

Comment: Are logarithms accepted ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recall the AM-GM inequality is given by
\begin{align}
\sqrt[n]{a_1a_2\ldots a_n} \leq \frac{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n}{n}
\end{align}
then it follows
\begin{align}
\sqrt[n]{(n!)^3}=\sqrt[n]{1^3\cdot 2^3\cdots n^3} \leq \frac{1^3+2^3+\cdots+n^3}{n} = \frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2 = \frac{n(n+1)^2}{4}.
\end{align}
Here I used the sum of cubes formula.

Comment: do you mean $1^\color{red}{3}+2^\color{red}{3}+...$?

Comment: @user715522 Yes. Thanks for pointing out the typo.

Comment: But it is a strict inequality as per the question.

Comment: @DerekLuna AM-GM inequality is equality if and only if $a_1=a_2 =\ldots = a_n$ which is not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you mean for n>1.

$n! <n^n$ (obvious).

$\frac{(n+1)^2}{4} \ge n\times1$

$\frac{(n+1)^2}{4} \ge (n-1)\times2$.

....

....

.....

Now solve individualy for n=odd and even.

In each case you get $n!<(\frac{n+1}{2})^n$

Comment: You could have given this as a hint in comments

Comment: That's what I am saying, you neither provided a hint nor gave a full detailed solution