# Inequality $(n!)^3<n^n(n+1/2)^{2n}$

Tags: inequality, factorial

$(n!)^3<n^n((n+1)/2)^{2n}$

I've been trying to solve this problem. I've tried using these relations:
$n^2(n+1/2)^2=$Sum of cubes of first n natural numbers
$(n(n+1)/2)=$Sum of first n natural numbers

But still I'm unable to solve this. Can you please help me?

Comment: Your equation is not clearly stated

Comment: Try to prove it using induction

Comment: Your attempts in the post also suggest you meant $(n+1)/2$ instead of $n+1/2$ (the parenthesis are important!) since $n^2((n+1)/2)^2=1^3+2^3+\dots+n^3$ as you mention. Unfortunately you have already got 3 answers for the incorrect version of the statement.

Comment: For what you probably intented to solve, see [Proving $(n!)^3<n^n\times\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)^{2n}$ with high school math](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3548414)

Answer (score 6):

We have for positive integer $n$,
$$n!\leq n^n\implies n!^3\leq n^{3n}< (n^3+n^2+n/4)^n=[n (n+1/2)^{2}]^n=n^n(n+1/2)^{2n}$$

Answer (score 2):

Proof by induction:
For $n=1$ it holds.
Assume that it holds for $n$ we have to prove that it holds for $n+1$, or that:
$$
(n+1)^3\lt \frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{n^n}\frac{(n+1+\frac12)^{2n+2}}{(n+\frac12)^{2n}}
$$
which is the same as:
$$
(n+1)^2\lt(n+1+\frac12)^2(1+\frac1n)^n(1+\frac1{n+\frac12})^{2n}
$$
or that
$$
(n+1)^2\lt(n+1+\frac12)^2
$$
which is clearly true.

Answer (score 1):

Proving $$(n!)^3<n^n\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2 n}$$ is the same as proving
$$3\log(n!) < n\log(n)+2n \log\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)$$ Using Stirling approximation for the lhs and Taylor for the rhs
$$\text{rhs - lhs}=3 n+\left(1-\frac{3}{2} \log (2 \pi  n)\right)-\frac{1}{2 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ which is true $\forall n \geq 1$.